# Enum equalization with other classes

Tags: dart, enums, equality

I've created a class that only takes `Enum`s as parameters. I figured I could create a third `Enum` where I would manually put every option so they have a better naming.

The only thing is, I can't test if both my third `Enum` instance and my class instance with the same parameters are equal just by using the `==` operator. Tried using `equatable` and considering the `Enum` instance as my class instance since it does implement it, but nothing works. Of course, I could create a test where all my given parameters are equal, but I just wondered whether I could do something so they return `true` when using the `==` operator.

E.g.:

#### Configuration

```dart
enum A {
  a,
  b;
}
enum B {
  c,
  d;
}

class Class with EquatableMixin {
  const EveryDayOfYear({required this.aValue, required this.bValue});

  final A aValue;
  final B bValue;
  
  @override
  List<Object?> get props => [aValue, bValue];
}

enum C {
  ac(Class(aValue: A.a, bValue: B.c)),
  ad(Class(aValue: A.a, bValue: B.d)),
  bc(Class(aValue: A.b, bValue: B.c)),
  bd(Class(aValue: A.b, bValue: B.d));

  const C(this._handler);

  final Class _handler;

  @override
  A get aValue => _handler.aValue;

  @override
  B get bValue => _handler.bValue;

  @override
  List<Object?> get props => [aValue, bValue];
}
```

#### Objective

```dart
final instance = Class(aValue: A.a, bValue: B.c);
instance == C.ac; // I would like something so this operation returns true.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As commented by [@Levi-Lesches](https://github.com/Levi-Lesches) [here](https://github.com/dart-lang/language/issues/2414#issuecomment-1219732598) the answer to my problem was to override my `operator ==`:

```dart
  @override
  // ignore: hash_and_equals, already implemented by EquatableMixin
  bool operator ==(Object other) {
    return (super == other) ||
        ((other is Class) &&
            (week == other.aValue) &&
            (day == other.bValue));
  }
```

This solved my problem and is fair since my class instance is not an `Enum`, but my enum constant is actually my class instance.